# How can I get focused element (<em>)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have such a structure:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
   <em class="class1">__<em>
   <em class="class2">:<em>
   <em class="class1">__<em>
   <em class="class2">:<em>
   <em class="class1">__<em>
</div>
```

How i can get DOM or JQuery object of focused `<em>` ? 
`document.activeElement` return general `<div>` 
`window.getSelection().focusNode` return text of focused `<em>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `em` tag should really only be used to style the text of an element, and that can be done using CSS with better effectiveness. That being said, you can hunt down the focused element using something like this:

```
window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement;
```

That will return the actual `em` element you are looking for. You can probably get a better hold on that using a jQuery selector:

```
$(window.getSelection().focusNode.parentElement);
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1evc2Lfe/)

Comment: The em element should *never* be used to style text. It should be used to indicate that stress emphasis should be placed on its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Find a query to match all the elements for what you are interesed to know if them are focussed or not, for example

```
$("[contenteditable=true] em")
```

Then, suscribe to focus event

```
var lastFocused;
$("[contenteditable=true] em").focus(function(e) {
  lastFocused = e.target;
});
```

You will have the focused element on lastFocused var, make sure to restrict what type of element you want on selector if possible